# Xubuntu 11.10 login issues

Tags: login, ubuntu-11.10, xubuntu

This is the second time this has happened to me this week. The first time was on my netbook, the second on a VM on my desktop. Whenever I try to log in to my account through the GUI the screen flashes black, then I arrive back at the log in prompt. I can log in to my account through the terminal (Ctrl-Alt-F1), and I can log in to a guest account. However, I can't log in via "normal" means.

Has anyone else had this issue? If so, care to shed some light on this problem?

Comment: Probably, your X server or session manager crashes.  Run after a failed login `dmesg | tail` to see for any segfault messages and have a look into the log files in `/var/log/`

Comment: Did you install "Compiz" and its plug-ins ??! if so, then you should remove them then try again